# (.htaccess Redirects) Removing end slash on urls which contain # that link to a section on the page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have just pushed a clients brand new website live and have found that many of the old links that have been indexed by Google no longer work. I have set up the following redirects in the .htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301 /faq /#/faqs
Redirect 301 /products /
Redirect 301 /faqs /#/faqs
Redirect 301 /carrageenan /
Redirect 301 /stockists-2 /#/stockists
Redirect 301 /contact-us /#/contact
Redirect 301 /our-story /#/our-story
Redirect 301 /thank-you /
Redirect 301 /uncategorized/almo-interview/ /
```

Here is an example:

Visiting `https://almomilk.com.au/#/our-story` actually scrolls you down the page to that specific section. The redirect works fine for that old url but it is adding a final `/` to the url (`almomilk.com.au/#/our-story/`) which is breaking that javascript functionality. I have spent hours trying to figure out how to remove that trailing slash at the end of the url in my redirect but have had no success.

These are the redirects that I'm having issues with:

```
Redirect 301 /stockists-2 /#/stockists
Redirect 301 /contact-us /#/contact
Redirect 301 /our-story /#/our-story
Redirect 301 /faq /#/faqs
Redirect 301 /faqs /#/faqs
```

**Example:** If you visit `https://almomilk.com.au/contact-us/` it should redirect to `almomilk.com.au/#/contact` **NOT** `almomilk.com.au/#/contact/`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any other rules in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /contact-us /#/contact
> ```

The "problem" with the mod_alias `Redirect` directive is that it's *prefix matching* and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. This is what's happening here, you are requesting `/contact-us/` (with a trailing slash), `/contact-us` matches the source URL in the directive (with `/` left over) and this remainder is then appended to the target URL. If you were to request `/contact-us/<anything>` then you will be redirected to `/#/contact/<anything>`.

If the request is `/contact-us/` (with a trailing slash) then this is what you should be matching. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ /#/contact
```

This will redirect `/contact-us/` to `/#/contact` (your immediate problem). However, it won't match `/contact-us` (no trailing slash) and it will still match `/contact-us/<anything>`, but this time it will redirect to `/#/contact<anything>` (note the missing slash) - which may be undesirable, although this *should* presumably return a 404 (although if it's JS then maybe not?).

Alternatively, use `RedirectMatch` instead, which uses regex instead of simple prefix matching. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/contact-us/?$ /#/contact
```

This will redirect `/contact-us` or `/contact-us/` to `/#contact` only.

Change the 302 to 301 (if that is the intention) only once you have confirmed it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

*You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.*

Comment: Perfect answer mate! Everything is working great now. Thanks so much.